# What target folder should I install my application to that will never require uac elevation?

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer, user-profile

I have an app and I am working on the installer for it.  Assuming that I want the installation to not require elevation and I want the application itself to never require elevation and I want the updater for the application (which is build in) to never require elevation where should I install the application to?

Caveats:

1. This application is not signed.
2. I am okay if each user has to install it separately under their profile.
3. Can I use the registry in the install and accomplish the same goal?
4. The only writes it makes are to setttings/configuration files.
5. .NET 4 app.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the path from WIX or from .NET? The two are different.

Answer (score 3):

A common choice is the local appdata folder returned by `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA)` (Win2K and later) or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData)` (Vista and later).

This returned path is something like:

- "C:\Users\arx\AppData\Local" (Vista and later)
- "C:\Documents and Settings\arx\Local Settings\Application Data" (pre-Vista)

It's normal to create company name and application folders under here, so you'll finish up with a path like:

"C:\Users\arx\AppData\Local\BlahSoft\BlahApplication"

**Update**

If you want this path from .Net you need `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`

Comment: `SHGetKnownFolderPath` is a Win32 API, not .NET nor WIX. Also, `FOLDERID_LocalAppData` is to the application *data* folder, not the installed programs folder.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is tagged both WIX and .NET; the two have different syntaxes for known-folder paths. The .NET command to get the current user application folder is `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs)`.

If you want to install to a WIX path, it has predefined properties for each known folder; `[ProgramFilesFolder]` is to the 32-bit application folder and `[ProgramFiles64Folder]` is to the 64-bit folder.

Comment: There isn't a per-user installed programs directory, so per-user programs tend to use the local app data directory.  The SpecialFolder.Programs directory is for start-menu shortcuts, not for program files.  [ProgramFilesFolder] and [ProgramFiles64Folder] require elevation.